# ¿Cómo depurar saltos de línea ('\rn', '\n') de un input? (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x

Tengo este código que busca el carácter que más se repite en un texto:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# contar.py
 
import collections
import timeit
from decimal import Decimal
 
cadena = input('Ingresar cadena: ')
 
start = timeit.default_timer()
 
L_max = collections.Counter((cadena).replace(' ', '')).most_common(2)
 
end = timeit.default_timer()
 
print('Los dos más repetidos', L_max, 'de un total de', len((cadena).replace(' ', '')),
                            'caracteres')
 
print('El más repetido, la letra |', L_max[0][0], '|', L_max[0][1], 'veces.')
 
print('Tiempo de respuesta', (str(format((end-start), '.8f'))), 'segs')
```

El problema se presenta cuando el texto a analizar contiene saltos de línea ('\rn', '\n'), el código sólo analiza texto hasta que encuentra un ('\rn', '\n'), omitiendo del análisis el texto que va a continuación del salto de línea.

He creado una función para depurar esos saltos de línea ('\rn', '\n') del texto antes de que sea analizado. La función es esta:

```
def limpiar_espacio(cadena):
    s = s.replace('\rn', '')
    s = s.replace('\t', '')
    s = s.replace('\f', '')
    s = s.replace('\n', '')
    return cadena
```

He implementado la función en el código así:

```
import collections
import timeit
from decimal import Decimal

cadena = input('Ingresar cadena: ')

def limpiar_espacio(cadena):
    s = s.replace('\rn', '')
    s = s.replace('\t', '')
    s = s.replace('\f', '')
    s = s.replace('\n', '')
    return cadena

start = timeit.default_timer()

limpiar_espacio(cadena)

L_max = collections.Counter((cadena).replace(' ', '')).most_common(2)

end = timeit.default_timer()

print('Los dos más repetidos', L_max, 'de un total de', len((cadena).replace(' ', '')),
                            'caracteres')

print('El más repetido, la letra |', L_max[0][0], '|', L_max[0][1], 'veces.')

print('Tiempo de respuesta', (str(format((end-start), '.8f'))), 'segs')
```

No entiendo qué estoy haciendo mal, pues sigue presentándose el mismo problema, toma texto hasta el primer salto de línea y, omite todo el texto después del salto de línea.

Nota: sí antes de usar el texto a analizar, lo paso por un editor como el `Notepad++`, y le quito los saltos de línea, al pasarlo al `input('Ingresar cadena: ')` el código funciona bien, elimina los espacios con `(cadena).replace(' ', '')`, hace el recuento de caracteres y devuelve los dos más repetidos.
He puesto el `.most_common(2)` a dos, puesto que sí analizo una palabra como `esternocleidomastoideo`, caso 'especial' puesto que en los 22 caracteres `Los dos más repetidos [('e', 4), ('o', 4)]`, tanto la 'a' como la 'e' tienen la misma cantidad de ocurrencias, situación que mi segundo `print` no reflejaría (sí hay alguna sugerencia para este tipo de casos, la acepto).

Espero no haber sido demasiado extenso en la presentación de mi pregunta.

Un saludo cordial y, mi agradecimiento antipado

JPablos-

Comment: Puedes probar con solo `\r` en vez de `\rn` en el primer `replace`?

Comment: Por cierto acabo de notar que en la función `limpiar_espacio` estás reemplazando en la variable `s`, no en el parámetro `cadena`

Comment: Gracias @FedericoMeza he corregido la función `s` por `cadena` y `\rn` por `\r`. Le he pasado un texto con varios saltos de línea y, persiste el problema.

Comment: Hmm, yo lo probé y funcionó. Pero estoy en Linux donde el salto de línea es solo `\n`, tal vez en Windows no funciona al tener otro salto de línea. Voy a instalar Python en Windows rápidamente a ver si identifíco el problema.

Comment: @FedericoMeza, también uso Linux, por tanto pienso que no es problema de SO.

Comment: Ah, pensé que estabas en Windows por el `\rn`. En Unix el salto de línea no incluye el \r. Entonces voy a poner una respuesta con una función `limpiar_espacio` para que me digas si te funciona.

Comment: Ya entiendo el problema. La función `input` no acepta entrada multilínea.

Comment: @FedericoMeza, Gracias.
Imagino que no hay más remedio que depurar el texto en un editor de texto antes de pasarlo al `input`.

Comment: Tengo una solución que no es óptima pero funciona. Ya estoy redactando la respuesta.

Comment: @FedericoMeza. Y en cuanto a la palabra `esternocleidomastoideo` que reporta dos letras con igual número de ocuurencias, ¿cómo podría presentar el segundo `print`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradezco la prontitud y colaboración en dar solución a mi pregunta.

Tomando nota de las repuestas y comentarios, he de decir, que las asignaciones `input` en Python3, no admiten ingresar texto multilínea, al menos en el contexto de mi código; en consecuencia el texto debe ser tratado previamente en un editor externo como `Notepad++`, por nombrar alguno, para así eliminar los saltos de línea (`\rn, \n´).

En cuanto a los 'casos especiales' como la palabra `esternocleidomastoideo` que reporta dos ocurrencias máximas iguales, me he servido de la respuesta aportada por @FedericoMeza, para introducir un bucle `for` que permita reflejar en el `print` la respuesta apropiada.

El código mejorado ha quedado así:

```
import collections
import timeit
from decimal import Decimal


cadena = input(('''Ingresar cadena: ''').replace('\n', ''))

start = timeit.default_timer()

L_max = collections.Counter((cadena.replace(' ', ''))).most_common(2)

L_max = list(filter(lambda f: f[1] == L_max[0][1], L_max))

if len(L_max) == 1:
    print('El carácter más repetido |', L_max[0][0], '|', L_max[0][1], 'veces de ',len(cadena), 'caracteres')

else:
    salida = f'Los {len(L_max)} más repetidos son | '
    for i in range(len(L_max)):
        if i > 0 and i < len(L_max)-1: salida += ', '
        if i == len(L_max)-1: salida += ' , '
        salida += L_max[i][0]
    salida += f' |; se repiten {L_max[0][1]} veces c/uno, en un total de {len(cadena)} carácteres'
        
    print(salida)
    
end = timeit.default_timer()

print('Tiempo de respuesta', (str(format((end-start), '.8f'))), 'segs')
```

¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Para aceptar entrada multilínea tenemos que ir leyendo línea por línea hasta encontrarnos con una línea vacía. La única desventaja es que en la última línea hay que presionar enter dos veces.

Y luego para el print al final lo compliqué un poco pero espero que te sirva.

```py
import collections

lineas = []
print('Ingrese la cadena: ', end='')
while True:
    #Leemos una línea
    linea = input()
    if linea:
        #Si la línea no está vacía la agregamos al arreglo de lineas
        lineas.append(linea)
    else:
        #Si no, terminamos el bucle
        break

#Creamos la cadena uniendo las lineas y eliminando el 'whitespace'
cadena = ''.join(lineas).replace(' ', '').replace('\n', '').replace('\r', '').replace('\t', '').replace('\f', '')

#Hallamos la frecuencia de cada letra
frecuencias = collections.Counter(cadena).most_common()

#Filtramos la lista de frecuencias para que queden solo aquellos caracteres cuya frecuencia sea igual a la frecuencia máxima
frecuencias = list(filter(lambda f: f[1] == frecuencias[0][1], frecuencias))

if len(frecuencias) == 1:
    print(f'El caracter más repetido es {frecuencias[0][0]} con una frecuencia de {frecuencias[0][1]} de un total de {len(cadena)} caracteres')
else:
    out = f'Los {len(frecuencias)} caracteres más repetidos son '
    for i in range(len(frecuencias)):
        if i > 0 and i < len(frecuencias)-1: out += ', '
        if i == len(frecuencias)-1: out += ' y '
        out += frecuencias[i][0]
    out += f'; cada uno con una frecuencia de {frecuencias[0][1]} de un total de {len(cadena)} caracteres'
    print(out)
```

Comment: Nada, solo toma el primer párrafo.

Comment: @JPablos esos párrafos están separados por una línea en blanco? De ser así la única forma de leer el texto completo sería ponerlo en un archivo de texto y leerlo con `open('archivo.txt', 'r').read()`

Comment: Finalmente he admitido que el texto debe ser tratado en un editor externo para eliminar los saltos de línea. He usado el bucle `for` de tu respuesta para reformular mi código para casos especiales; funciona muy bien y con bajo impacto en el tiempo de respuesta.
Gracias por la colaboración.

Answer (score 0):

Parece que cuando python toma la cadena del `input()` la convierte en: `Hola \\tMundo`.
Entonces modifica el filtro con:

```
cadena = cadena.replace('\\t', '')
cadena = cadena.replace('\\n', '')
# ...etc
```

Comment: Hechas las modificaciones sigue sin funcionar. Llega sólo hasta el primer salto de línea.